# Quality of Reduction of finite automata using different congruences

Tags: automata, reductions, finite-automata

I am looking for an example, which corresponds to what I've learned in my Applied Automata Theory Class:

Given a NFA $\mathcal{A}$,

- a $\approx _\mathcal{A}$ quotient automaton can be bigger then a $\sim_\mathcal{A}$ quotient automaton and this can be bigger than an optimal quotient
- and an optimal quotient does not need to be the smallest equivalent NFA.

$\approx _\mathcal{A}$ denotes the bisimulation relation (block refinement algorithm) and $\sim_\mathcal{A}$ denotes the canonical congruence, where $p \sim_\mathcal{A} q \text{ iff } \delta^*(p,w) \in F \text{ iff } \delta^*(q,w) \in F$, where DFA $\mathcal{A}= (Q, \Sigma, q_0, \delta, F)$.

Follow-up:

The original Automaton $\mathcal{A}$ over $\Sigma={\{a,b\}}$ recognizing $\mathcal{L} = \Sigma a^*$:

The original automaton $\mathcal{A} = (\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}, \Sigma, 1, \Delta, \{{3,4}\}) $ with $\Delta$:
\begin{pmatrix}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
1 &- & b & a & -& -&- &  \\
2 &b & b & - & a & -&- &  \\
3 &- & b & - & a& a&- &  \\
4 &- & b & - & a& a&- &  \\
5 &- & - & - & -& -&b &  \\
6 &- & - &  & a& b&b &  \\
\end{pmatrix}

The quotient automaton $\mathcal{A}_{\approx}  = (\{12,34,5,6\}, \Sigma, 12, \Delta_{\approx}, \{{34}\}) $ with $\Delta_{\approx}$:
\begin{pmatrix}
& 12 & 34 & 5 & 6\\
12 &b & a & - & - \\
34 &b & a & a & - \\
5 &- & - & - & b \\
6 &- & a & b & b  \\
\end{pmatrix}

The quotient automaton $\mathcal{A}_{\sim}  = (\{126,34,5\}, \Sigma, 126, \Delta_{\sim}, \{{34}\}) $ with $\Delta_{\sim}$:
\begin{pmatrix}
& 126 & 34 & 5 \\
126 &b & a & b \\
34 &b & a & a  \\
5 &b & - & -  \\
\end{pmatrix}

The optimal quotient automaton $\mathcal{A_{OPT}}  = (\{1256,34\}, \Sigma, 1256, \Delta_{OPT}, \{{34}\}) $ with $\Delta_{OPT}$:
\begin{pmatrix}
& 1256 & 34 \\
1256 &a,b & a \\
34 &a,b & a  \\
\end{pmatrix}

The first property is satisfied since $\mathcal{A}_{\approx}$ has 4 states and $\mathcal{A}_{\sim}$ has 3 states. But in my example $\mathcal{A}_{OPT}$ is the smallest automaton recognizing the given language. When do they differ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's instructive to compute these relations for a few simple languages. This way, either you'll find an example, or you can conclude that it's often the case that these relations are the same.

Comment: I found an example constructing an NFA for the Language $L = \Sigma a^*$.

Comment: Can you post an answer with the details?

Comment: Please see above